# layouts problem please see the attached file

Tags: laravel

```
@section('content')
    <!-- Jumbotron -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>{{$company->name}}</h1>
        <p class="lead">{{$company->description}}</p>
      <!--  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>  -->
    </div>

    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($company->projects as project)
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>{{ $project->name }}</h2>
                <p class="text-danger">{{ $project->description  }}</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/projects/{{$project->id}}" role="button">View details »</a></p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: C:\Users\system Admin\Desktop\social-login\resources\views\companies\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `foreach` statement. You miss the '$'. It should be:

```
...
@foreach($company->projects as $project)
...
```